# e.preventDefault only at first action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script:

```
var submited = false;
$('.trx-form').one('submit', function(e){
    if(!submited){
        e.preventDefault();

        var i = 0, $this = $(this);
        (function conf(){
            $.confirm({
                title: 'Confirm Action',
                content: 'Yakin data yang dimasukan sudah benar?',
                closeIcon: 'fa fa-close',
                theme: 'dark',
                confirm: function(){
                    if(i < 2){
                        i++; submited = true;
                        conf();
                    }else{
                        $('.trx-form').trigger('submit');
                    }
                },
                cancel: function(){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        })();
    }
});
```

on first click on submit button the confirmation dialog popup for 3 times, after that the form should be submited without the popup. it's working if I click the submit button once again, but not with `$('.trx-form').trigger('submit')`. anyone knows the problem?

Comment: `$('.trx-form').one` **one**?

Comment: Try  $('.trx-form').submit()

Comment: @guradio yep, one http://api.jquery.com/one

Comment: @PrashantAgrawal: did that, same result.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan many thanks mate :)

Comment: Instead of $('.trx-form').one('submit', function(e){} do $('.trx-form').on('submit', function(e){}

Comment: I guess you are using .one(), it will call the handler once and then it will unbind from the submit event

Comment: `Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.` if you trigger submit already you cant trigger it again maybe that is the reason

Comment: An additional not to the answers: your `e.preventDefault();` in the `cancel: function(){ ... }`  is useless and might even throw an error. The event `e` will be already finished when the the async callback is called.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the **$().one** function which means it can be clicked once, how about **$("").on("")**

Answer (score 0):

`one` is only executed once and will unbind the event after the first execution.

Try using `on` to bind the event and handle multiple clicks if needed.

Comment: i did `on` before i use `one`, both return the same result. beside that, i want to popup a confirmation dialog 3 times at first time user click on submit button. if user absolutely sure about what they are going to post, then post it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this:

```
var submited = false;
$(document).on("submit", ".trx-form", function(e) {

    $this = $(this);
    if(!submited){
        e.preventDefault();

        var i = 0, 


        (function conf(){
            $.confirm({
                title: 'Confirm Action',
                content: 'Yakin data yang dimasukan sudah benar?',
                closeIcon: 'fa fa-close',
                theme: 'dark',
                confirm: function(){
                    if(i < 2){
                        i++; submited = true;
                        conf();
                    }else{
                         $this.submit();
                    }
                },
                cancel: function(){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        })();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyone that answered my question. I fix it with much help from

```
var submited = false;
$('.trx-form').on('submit', function(e){
    if(!submited){
        e.preventDefault();

        var i = 0, $this = $(this);
        (function conf(){
            $.confirm({
                title: 'Confirm Action',
                content: 'Yakin data yang dimasukan sudah benar?',
                closeIcon: 'fa fa-close',
                confirmButton: 'Ok',
                cancelButton: 'Cancel',
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary',
                cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
                theme: 'black',
                confirm: function(){
                    if(i < 2){
                        i++; submited = true;
                        conf();
                    }else{
                        $('[name="submit"], #_submit').click();
                    }
                },
                cancel: function(){
                    submited = false;
                }
            });
        })();
    }
});
```

first, instead of doing `submit()` or `trigger('submit')` I do `click()` on the submit button. second, I forget the popup should re-appear if the user hit cancel button and then resubmit the form, so i use `on()` instead of `one()`, because `one()` as it descripted only handle the event one time, it will unreg itself on second chance.